# $match in aggregate don't return data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match, aggregate-functions

I have three tables below is the structure like below
[image: Structure of the tables]

**I'm looking to get a result like below**

```
"type1": [ -- type from Accounts collection
            {
                "_id": "5e97e9a224f62f93d5x3zz46", -- _id from Accounts collection
                "locs": "sampleLocks 1", -- field from Accounts collection
                "solutions": "sample solutions 1", -- field from Accounts collection
                "Clause": "clause 1" -- field from AccountsDesc collection
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e97e9a884f62f93d5x3zz46", 
                "locs": "sampleLocks2",
                "solutions": "sample solutions2", 
                "Clause": "clause2" 
            }
        ],

        "type2": [
         // same data construction as of type1 above
        ]
```

1. _id, locks, solution to be coming from **Accounts collection**
2. Clause field to be coming from AccountsDesc collection
3. accounts_id is kind of a foreign key in AccountsDesc coming from Account
4. competitor_id is kind of a foreign key in AccountsDesc coming from Competitor

**Below is what my query looks like**

```
db.accountDesc.aggregate([
  { 
        $match : {accounts_Id : "123456"}, active: true}
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'accounts',
        pipeline: [{ $match: { type: { $in: ["type1, type2, type3"] } } }],
        as: 'accountsData'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {

      _id: "$accountsData.type",
      data: {
           $push:  {_id: "$accountsData._id", clause: "$clause", locs: "$type.locs",  solutions: "$type.solutions"}
       }
    }
  },
   {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
            data: {
                $push: {
                    k: {
                        $toString: '$_id'
                    },
                    v: '$data'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: '$data'
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Issues related with the query -

1. `$match : {accountId : "123456"}, active: true}` -- No data is returned if i use match on AccountsDesc collection
2. cant set localField, foriegnField if im using pipeline, then how the mapping will happen like a LEFT join.
3. clause: `"$clause"` don't get the value of this field in the response

Comment: Your data field doesn't match with table structure (like "clause", "accountId"), so please, provide us MongoDB sample data for all tables

Comment: @Valijon - i have updated the data object in the question. Also i have given a comment as to which field will come from which collection. accountId is kind of a foreignKey in AccountDesc, which comes from Accounts collection.

Comment: I see. Is it possible sample data? You can share it in https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: @Valijon - not sure if this is what you are expecting, https://mongoplayground.net/p/L7YWYF8bBvR 
because my structure is the same.

Comment: Fill please collections with real sample data, where `accountDesc` should have `accountId` field in order to reproduce your query https://mongoplayground.net/p/8LG3_K9vIal

Comment: @Valijon - ok, i have updated that
https://mongoplayground.net/p/BPTmL4XQFI3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211789/discussion-between-valijon-and-sam-sam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in chat, you want RIGHT OUTER JOIN for your aggregation.

Try the query below:

```
db.User_Promo_Map.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user_Id: ObjectId("5e8c1180d59de1704ce68112")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "promo",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            active: true,
            platform: {
              $in: [
                "twitch",
                "youtube",
                "facebook"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "accountsData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$accountsData"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$accountsData.platform",
      data2: {
        $addToSet: {
          amount: "$amount",
          promo_Id: "$promo_Id"
        }
      },
      data: {
        $addToSet: {
          _id: "$accountsData._id",
          format: "$accountsData.format",
          description: "$accountsData.description"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "data",
          in: {
            "_id": "$$data._id",
            "description": "$$data.description",
            "format": "$$data.format",
            amount: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$data2",
                initialValue: "$$REMOVE",
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.promo_Id",
                        "$$data._id"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$this.amount",
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: {
            $toString: "$_id"
          },
          v: "$data"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nHJvef3dRzt)